# How to close Toggle Navigation when users clicks outside the nav container in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

So I have a toggled navigation menu and inside that menu and I have another 2 ul menus. I want to implement a feature so If user clicks out of any navigation container toggle the navigation to close it self rather then clicking on the close button.  I want to make subNavActive, safNavAcitve and repNavUl = false again when the user clicks out of the Toggled Nav Container. 
    new Vue({
          el: '#app',

```
      data: {
        visible: false,
        home: true,
        show: false,
        active: false,
        subNavActive: false,
        safNavShow: false,
        repNavUl: false,
        admNavShow: false,
        rotateDropDown: false
      },
      methods: {}
    });
```

HTML CODE BELOW

```
 <div class="container">
                <!-- Main nav starts here  -->
                <!-- main nav vue transition below -->
                <transition name="slide-fade">
                    <!-- vue animation if/else below  -->
                    <nav class="main-nav" v-if="show">
                        <!-- Main nav header and title  -->
                        <div class="main-nav-header">
                            <h2>Hello User</h2>
                            <h3>Welcome Back</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="main-nav-container">
                            <!-- Main navigation ul list below  -->
                            <ul class="main-nav-ul">
                                <li>
                                    <li class="split-li">
                                        <span>
                                            <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>
                                        </span>
                                        MY SCHEDULE & BIDDING
                                        <a class="main-nav-spans" href="#">
                                            <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <li class="split-li">
                                        <span>
                                            <i class="fas fa-handshake"></i>
                                        </span>
                                        SAFETY
                                        <a class="main-nav-spans" @click="safNavShow = !safNavShow" href="#">
                                            <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <!-- Sub nav transition below -->
                                    <transition name="slide-right">
                                        <!-- vue animation if/else below  -->
                                        <div class="sub-nav saf-nav-toggle" v-if="safNavShow">
                                            <div class="sub-nav-header ">
                                                <h3>
                                                    <li class="split-li">
                                                        <span>
                                                            SAFETY
                                                        </span>

                                                        <a @click="safNavShow = !safNavShow" class="sub-nav-icons" href="#">
                                                            <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                                                        </a>
                                                    </li>

                                                </h3>
                                            </div>
                                            <ul class="sub-nav-menu">
                                                <li>
                                                    <li class="split-li">
                                                        <span>
                                                            Reporting
                                                        </span>

                                                        <a @click="repNavUl =!repNavUl, rotateDropDown =!rotateDropDown" v-bind:class="{ rotateDropDown: rotateDropDown }" class="main-nav-spans"
                                                            href="#">
                                                            <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
                                                        </a>
                                                    </li>


                                                    <transition name="rep-nav">
                                                        <ul class="sub-nav-ul" v-if="repNavUl">
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a href="#">I-21 Injury Reporting</a>
                                                            </li>
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a href="#">ASAP Reporting</a>
                                                            </li>
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a href="#">General ASAP Information</a>
                                                            </li>
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a href="#">Flight Attendent Incident Report</a>
                                                            </li>
                                                        </ul>
                                                    </transition>
                                                </li>

                                                <li>
                                                    <li class="split-li">
                                                        <span>
                                                            Agriculture & Customs
                                                        </span>
                                                        <a class="main-nav-spans" href="#">
                                                            <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
                                                        </a>
                                                    </li>

                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <li class="sub-first-nav-li">
                                                        <a href="#">Known Crewmember</a>
                                                    </li>
                                                </li>

                                                <li>
                                                    <li class="sub-first-nav-li">
                                                        <a href="#"> Products Safety Data Search</a>
                                                    </li>

                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </transition>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <li class="split-li no-arrow-li">
                                        <span>
                                            <i class="fas fa-users"></i>
                                        </span>
                                        <a href="#">TRAINING</a>
                                    </li>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <li class="split-li  ">
                                        <span>
                                            <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                                        </span>
                                        ADMINSTRATION
                                        <a class="main-nav-spans" @click="admNavShow = !admNavShow" href="#">
                                            <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <transition name="slide-right">
                                        <div class="sub-nav admin-nav-toggle" v-if="admNavShow">
                                            <div class="sub-nav-header">
                                                <h3>
                                                    <li class="split-li">
                                                        <span>
                                                            ADMINSTRATION
                                                        </span>

                                                        <a @click="admNavShow = !admNavShow" class="sub-nav-icons" href="#">
                                                            <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                                                        </a>
                                                    </li>

                                                </h3>
                                            </div>
                                            <ul>

                                                <li>
                                                    <li class="split-li">
                                                        <span>
                                                            OJI and Leaves
                                                        </span>
                                                        <a class="main-nav-spans" href="#">
                                                            <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
                                                        </a>
                                                    </li>

                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <li class="split-li">
                                                        <span>
                                                            Pay and Benefits
                                                        </span>
                                                        <a class="main-nav-spans" href="#">
                                                            <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
                                                        </a>
                                                    </li>

                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <li class="split-li">
                                                        <span>
                                                            Performace
                                                        </span>
                                                        <a class="main-nav-spans" href="#">
                                                            <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
                                                        </a>
                                                    </li>

                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <li class="sub-first-nav-li">
                                                        <a href="#">Inflight Resource Directory</a>
                                                    </li>

                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <li class="split-li">
                                                        <span>
                                                            Mobile and Web
                                                        </span>
                                                        <a class="main-nav-spans" href="#">
                                                            <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
                                                        </a>
                                                    </li>

                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <li class="sub-first-nav-li">
                                                        <a href="#">AFA</a>
                                                    </li>
                                                </li>

                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </transition>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <li class="split-li ">
                                        <span>
                                            <i class="fas fa-utensils"></i>
                                            CATERING & BRAND
                                        </span>
                                        <a class="main-nav-spans" href="#">

                                            <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>

                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <li class="split-li no-arrow-li">
                                        <span>
                                            <i class="fas fa-bed"></i>
                                        </span>
                                        <a href="#">HOTELS</a>
                                    </li>

                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <li class="split-li no-arrow-li">
                                        <span>
                                            <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
                                        </span>
                                        <a href="#">MY BASE</a>
                                    </li>

                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <li class="split-li no-arrow-li">
                                        <span>
                                            <i class="fas fa-certificate"></i>
                                        </span>
                                        <a href="#">RECOGNITION</a>
                                    </li>

                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <li class="split-li no-arrow-li">
                                        <span>
                                            <i class="fas fa-male"></i>
                                        </span>
                                        <a href="#">MY LEADERSHIP TEAM</a>
                                    </li>

                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                    </nav>
                </transition>
            </div>
```

Comment: Out of navigation

Comment: Done please check my updated code

Answer (score 2):

Tried using `Vue-Clickaway`?
https://github.com/simplesmiler/vue-clickaway

The solution can look something like this.

import { mixin as clickaway } from 'vue-clickaway';

```
export default {
  mixins: [ clickaway ],
  template: '<p v-on-clickaway="away">Click away</p>',
  methods: {
    away: function() {
      console.log('clicked away');
    },
  },
};
```